# Set notification text from permanent service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a service that's constantly running in the background and has a notification to inform about its current status. When you clicked the notification an activity would open that allows you to manage the service. That fully worked until I set

```
android:targetSdkVersion="23"
```

in the manifest.

Before that I would create my notification with this:

```
Notification myNotification = new Notification();
//several options
```

I would then update my notification's text with this:

```
myNotification.setLatestEventInfo
```

I'm afraid setLatestEventInfo was deprecated for a while and seems to have disappeared with sdk 23. Fine.

I then used Notification.Builder to create the notification. I'm trying to update the text with this:

```
notificationBuilder.setContentText(textToDisplay);
```

or this

```
notificationBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(textToDisplay));
```

but nothing works. It just displays a default text like "click here to display more information".

Then notification is not "started" with

```
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, myNotification);
```

but since it's from a service with

```
instance.startForeground(notificationId, myNotification);
```

Problem nr.1:

Text doesn't show, only "click for further information"

Problem nr.2:

A click will open the app info activity from the OS's settings menu. It should display the activity of my choice.

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the PendingIntent and builds the Notification?

Comment: That would be:

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMainTabLayout.class);
    myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Builder(AutomationService.getInstance());
    builder.setContentTitle("Automation");
    builder.setCategory(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    builder.setContentIntent(myPendingIntent);

However the above variables are created only once. After that I'm only trying to update the notificationBuilder's text.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for Notification indicates [three fields are required](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required): small icon, title, and detail text.  Small icon seems particularly important.  If it is missing, it appears the notification is judged "malformed" and the special handling [described here](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/MTinJWdNL8t) is applied. That handling includes display of a generic title in the notification, such as "app-name is running", and starting the App Info activity for the app when the notification is clicked.

The behavior you are seeing is because you are not setting a small icon when you build the notification. You also should specify [Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#CATEGORY_SERVICE) for the category, instead of Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE.

Comment: Hm, I believe that is more about a notification not showing at all because of an error, isn't it?

Comment: My understanding of the linked note is that if the notification is malformed, the system displays a special generic notification, maybe the one your seeing:  "Instead, what we ultimately did in 4.3 is have the system put up its own notification "

Comment: I bow to you, you were right. Also now the app is opened if you click the notification, not just the app info. Thanks a lot!